# Why are $E$ and $B$ fields not redundant?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

The good ol' Maxwell Equations have two very big concepts: the $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields. But it can be shown, adding relativity into the stew, that what we call the $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields are just a single Electromagnetic field. When talking about the same frame of reference, this Electromagnetic field behaves just like what we call the $\vec{E}$ field. And if the charge is viewed from a different frame of reference, after proper Lorentz Transformation, another force field seems to come into play which is what we call the $\vec{B}$ field. It's not a new concept.


But according to the [Wikepedia page of Relativistic Electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_electromagnetism):

> Relativistic electromagnetism is a modern teaching strategy....

Teaching strategy? Why isn't such an approach used more commonly? This would make understanding Electromagnetism more intuitive since all that's required that way is $\nabla\cdot\vec{E} = \rho_v/\epsilon$ (Gauss' Law) which is not to hard to explain. Why are Maxwell's Equations and $\vec{E}\,\vec{B}$ fields not regarded as "approximations" or "tools to make electromagnetism simpler"?


Moreover, permanent magnets work because of electron spin. Why does electron spin arise?
It's because of the bispinor wavefunction result of the Dirac Equation (going into quantum mechanics here), which is like older QM, *plus.......*? Special Relativity. Damn.
Its pretty easy for me to say here that all magnetism is a result of basic non-relativistic ideas plus relativity, but still this idea is not given as much attention as seeing how important it is. Is there a reason?

Comment: Absolutely no. The electromagnetic field does not behave like the $\vec{E}$ field. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism)

Comment: above quote from wiki is a good reason to always take wiki with a grain of salt. Anyway, your question is very confusing and hard to follow, would you mind boiling it down a bit?

Comment: Yes my framing of this question seems wrong. Will edit it. But the point of my question again is why both fields are still used so commonly.

Comment: @Sanya In short, why isn't $\vec{B}$ always replaced with Lorentz transformed $\vec{E}$ field?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The "proper" relativistic object would be neither the electric nor the magnetic field, but the Faraday tensor. Whose components you can organize into...the electric and the magnetic field! The two viewpoints - electromagnetic field strength tensor, or separate electric and magnetic fields - are completely equivalent, I'm not sure what you're so mad about.

Comment: @UditDey because we cannot always find a frame where all $\vec{B}$ fields vanish.

Comment: I suspect that you're thinking of the [electromagnetic four potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential), from which we get the Farady tensor that ACuriousMind mentions. I agree that understanding this is a good way to understand EM, but the four-potential is a complicated quantity. It's a four-vector field and it has a gauge freedom. Explaining this to students is veering awfully close to melting their brains.

Comment: Possible duplicates : [Does special relativity make magnetic fields irrelevant?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38151) and [The necessity of the B field](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38999)