# Can Maxwell's Equations be expressed only in terms of an electric field and special relativity?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

It is well known that the magnetic field is a consequence of special relativity, due to length contraction.

Because of this, I was wondering if you could express Maxwell's equations only in terms of the Electric field, and depending on the reference frame.

Imagine we have a test particle, moving with velocity $v$, with respect to the $S$ frame. The particle is at rest in the $S'$ frame. Now we will define the following vectors:
$$
\mathbf E: \text{Electric field in the $S$ frame}
$$
$$
\mathbf B: \text{Magnetic field in the $S$ frame}
$$
$$
\mathbf E': \text{Electric field in the $S'$ frame}
$$
$$
\mathbf B': \text{Magnetic field in the $S'$ frame}
$$
$$
\mathbf r: \text{position coordinates in the $S$ frame}
$$
$$
\mathbf r': \text{position coordinates in the $S'$ frame}
$$

Would be reasonable to do the following:
$$
\mathbf B(\mathbf r) = \mathbf E'(\mathbf r)
$$
$$
\mathbf B'(\mathbf r') = \mathbf 0
$$
It is possible to create such theory? Does this theory already exists?

Comment: $S'$ is traditionally the moving frame.

Comment: Stackexchange pages have a column titled: 'Related' For this question the top entry is a link to a 2011 question titled: [Can Maxwell's equations be derived from Coulomb's Law and Special Relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/can-maxwells-equations-be-derived-from-coulombs-law-and-special-relativity?rq=1) That question has many interesting answers.

Comment: Related: [Does special relativity make magnetic fields irrelevant?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38151/does-special-relativity-make-magnetic-fields-irrelevant) (Short answer: No! Longer answer: Absolutely not.)

Answer (score 5):

The quantities $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{B}$ and $|\vec{E}|^2-|\vec{B}|^2$ are Lorentz invariants. In particular, if the latter is negative (as it would be around eg a neutral current carrying wire, where $\vec{B}\neq\vec{0}$ but $\vec{E}=\vec{0}$) then there cannot be a Lorentz transformation such that in the new frame $\vec{B}=0$.